Concatenation of two regexes into one line in powershell script
I have this PowerShell script to detect directories on the basis of regular expression and subsequently delete these. How can I join these two lines join to one ? I tried apply some advices from internet but none of them worked for me.
    $directoryToDelete3 = Join-Path -Path $FrontendAppsDeploymentDirectory -ChildPath $application.ReverseProxyBaseUrl "[0-9][0-9][0-9]"
    $directoryToDelete6 = Join-Path -Path $FrontendAppsDeploymentDirectory -ChildPath $application.ReverseProxyBaseUrl "[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]"
    # delete these directories before deployment starts
    Get-ChildItem $directoryToDelete3 -Directory | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
    Get-ChildItem $directoryToDelete6 -Directory | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse

Thank for any advice how to solve it.

Don't think this is possible with WildcardPattern (what is being used by Get-ChildItem to find your folders) however you could do it with regex using Where-Object. See https://regex101.com/r/pPafdZ/1 for pattern details.
$directoryToDelete = Join-Path -Path $FrontendAppsDeploymentDirectory -ChildPath $application.ReverseProxyBaseUrl
Get-ChildItem $directoryToDelete -Directory |
    Where-Object Name -Match '^[0-9]{3}(-[0-9]{3})?$' |
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force

